# Property 'query' does not exist on type 'Vue'

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have one transfer.vue component as following.

```
<template>
    <transfer-panel ref="leftPanel">
    </transfer-panel>
</template>
        
<script lang="ts">
    import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
    import TransferPanel from './Transfer-Panel.vue';
        
    @Component({
        components: {
            TransferPanel
        }
    })
    export default class Transfer extends Vue {
        
        clearQuery(which: string) {
            (this.$refs.leftPanel as TransferPanel).query = ''; // Here it shows error.
        }
        
}
</script>
```

which uses transfer-panel.vue component of which definition is as following.

```
<template>
    <div class="dummy-div">
    </div>
</template>

import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({})
export default class TransferPanel extends Vue {
  query = '';
}
```

But on following line (mentioned in transfer.vue component)

```
(this.$refs.leftPanel as TransferPanel).query = '';
```

It shows error as following. What's wrong here?

*Property 'query' does not exist on type 'Vue'*

Comment: Can you provide code sandbox which had that error?

Comment: seems. im doing some very sily mistake here. i created stackblitz for same and there it is working. my vs code showing error.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vuejs-starter-typescript-m745su

Comment: it is picking up definition from following some how.
node_modules> element-ui > types > message-box.d.ts > vue/types/vue

Comment: Here is my[Forked Sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vuejs-starter-typescript-e8imeo?file=transfer.ts) and it is completely fine, I have no errors. Could you replicate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to your `transfer.vue` file

```js
<script lang="ts">
    import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
    import TransferPanel from './Transfer-Panel.vue';
        
    @Component({
        components: {
            TransferPanel
        }
    })
    export default class Transfer extends Vue {
      ...
      $refs!: {
        leftPanel: TransferPanel // TransferPanel interface should have query as a property
      }
      ...
    }
</script
```